# insertion of a list in additional dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, insertion

my first question, surfed a lot!

I have an array in Numpy, like

```
myarray=np.zeros((raws,cols))
```

then I have `raws*cols` one dimensional numpy array, all same lenght, let's say `deep`

then I would insert each one of this one dimensional array into `myarray`.

expected result:

```
newarray.shape
(raws,cols,deep)
```

I use this in a bigger function and the fact I operate this way is due to a parallelization paradigma.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @mgilson you need () around (5, 6) in zeroes [it's a tuple] and print(stacked.shape)

Comment: Are you looking for `np.stack`? `zeros = [np.zeros((5, 6)) for _ in range(7)]; stacked = np.stack(zeros, axis=-1); print(stacked.shape)` (perhaps with a reshape because it looks like you're planning on stacking flattened arrays)

Comment: np, maybe just post also as an anwer, since I think it solves the problem... ;)

Comment: it works, perfectly. Thanks